# Accessing text files in Windows 8 apps

Tags: c#, windows, asynchronous

I would like to set up a set of local text 'data' files and display them on a windows 8 app.

I can use something like this in a class:

```
public async void readFile()
{
    StorageFile storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Box__The.txt"));
    Stream stream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);   
    _strFile = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

which reads the file into a text string correctly and I can see that when I step through the code, but when I try to pass the result back to the main display code, it shows it as null.

Is this some issue to do with threads or something?

Comment: how you pass result to main display?

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    await readFile();
    label.Text = _strFile ;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // An exception occurred from the async operation
}
```